# Cassandra Clustering for 2 node

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I want to create a two node cluster in Cassandra. I have done following changes in my yaml file -

Example:

Node 1

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
    num_tokens: 256
    seed_provider: class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
parameters:
        ‐ seeds:  "10.168.66.41,10.176.170.59" 
listen_address:10.168.66.41
rpc_address:10.168.66.41   
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
auto_bootstrap : false
```

Node 2

```
cluster_name: 'MyCassandraCluster'
num_tokens: 256
seed_provider:     class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
parameters:
    ‐ seeds:  "10.168.66.41"
listen_address:10.176.170.59
rpc_address:10.176.170.59
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
auto_bootstrap : false
```

But still I am not able to create two node cluster. Why am I facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to know without seeing an actual error message from your system.log, but I'll take a guess.  It looks like you might have a chicken-before-the-egg problem, based on your seed nodes.

10.176.170.59 won't be able to start without 10.168.66.41 already running.  And while .41 has itself specified as a seed node, it also has .59 specified, which might throw things off.

My recommendation is to change your seed list to be the same on all (both) nodes.  Just set it to this on both:

```
seeds:  "10.168.66.41"
```

Then, start .41, which should come up.  Then start .59.

If that doesn't do it, look for exceptions in your system.log.

Comment: ok. I have done the same thing also . But by doing this, I am not able to start 10.176.170.59 Cassandra server.

Comment: And one thing more , when I run nodetool command on seed node, it does not show other node.

Comment: Are you able to understand, what am I trying to say. 
D:\apache-cassandra-3.10\bin>nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.168.66.41  224.45 KiB  256          100.0%            c0fd9946-c69a-4589-bee5-c234512dd743  rack1

Comment: So , you can see in the output, there is no information about second node. 10.168.66.41

Comment: @Ravi So what does .59 say in its log about why it won't run?  I'm guessing that it says something like `cannot gossip with any seed nodes`...

Answer (score 0):

Auto bootstrap should be set to true when a new node is added in a cluster.
So set auto bootstrap to true and set your seed node as one node E.g. in your case it 10.168.66.41 (or) 10.176.70.59.

- Start your seed node first
- Telnet your seed node and storage port (default 7000) from your secondary node, if not able to telnet then check your firewall settings.
- Start your secondary node now

Comment: Thanks Shoban. Secondry node had different firewall settings.So I have raise a request for changing firewall setting. Hope so, this time its works.